# Split a string if starts with RQ in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a string like:

```
RQ12123RQ32434RQu9798
```

I need to split the string by RQ. Expected output id:

```
RQ12123,RQ32434,RQu9798
```

My code:

```
WrdArray() = Split(Sheets(SdomCompareResultSheet).Cells(i, 5).Value)
```

Comment: Do you expect the output into one cell or three?

Comment: iam expecting output in an array , for the above scenario array size should be 3

Comment: my code WrdArray() = Split(Sheets(SdomCompareResultSheet).Cells(i, 5).Value)

Comment: not vba but formula: `=MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "RQ", ",RQ"), 2, 999)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**sticking to your code:**

```
Dim WrdArray As Variant

WrdArray = Split(Trim(Replace(Sheets(SdomCompareResultSheet).Cells(i, 5).Value, "RQ", " RQ")))
```

---

**a more generic code:**

```
Function GetArray(strng As String, id As String) As Variant
    GetArray = Split(Trim(Replace(strng, id, " " & id)))
End Function
```

which you could exploit in your "main" sub as follows

```
Sub main()
    Dim WrdArray As Variant
    Dim strng As String

    strng = "RQ12123RQ32434RQu9798"
    WrdArray = GetArray(strng, "RQ")

End Sub
```

---

**a little less generic code**

suppose you know that the first two letters are *always* the id to parse the string through:

```
Function GetArray(strng As String) As Variant
    GetArray = Split(Trim(Replace(strng, Left(strng, 2), " " & Left(strng, 2))))
End Function
```

to be exploited like follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim WrdArray As Variant
    Dim strng As String

    strng = "RQ12123RQ32434RQu9798"
    WrdArray = GetArray(strng)

End Sub
```

Comment: is this a generic solution or only for this data, iam expecting a generic one

Comment: it's a generic solution adapted to the code you showed in the question. Just substitute `Sheets(SdomCompareResultSheet).Cells(i, 5).Value` with `s` with `s` being the string you want to process

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As String, t As String

    s = "RQ12123RQ32434RQu9798"
    t = Mid(Replace(s, "RQ", ",RQ"), 2)
    MsgBox t
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Every occurrence  of "RQ" in the input string will get a coma prepended to it *(except the first "RQ")*

**EDIT#2:**

To store the result in an array:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As String, t As String

    s = "RQ12123RQ32434RQu9798"
    t = Mid(Replace(s, "RQ", ",RQ"), 2)
    MsgBox t

    ary = Split(t, ",")
End Sub
```

Comment: will this code work if there multiple ids starts with RQ?

Comment: i need the result to be stored in an array

Comment: @PrakashSingh  See my **EDIT#2**

Comment: That is very neat.